# kubectl get pods does not show READY-STATUS-RESTARTS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run `kubectl get pods` on my cluster I only get `NAME` and `AGE` information. I cannot see anything about `READY-STATUS-RESTARTS.` The `-o` wide flag doesn't help either.

This is my client version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.1", GitCommit:"d647ddbd755faf07169599a625faf302ffc34458", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-02T17:01:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.5", GitCommit:"f01a2bf98249a4db383560443a59bed0c13575df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-19T15:50:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Your client and server versions are different, please update it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl

Comment: You can use 'describe' to see the status and if the pod is ready: $ kubectl describe pod <pod_name>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your client version.

Change your client version to v1.14.0 using the following commands (on Mac):

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.0/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

chmod +x ./kubectl

sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

And try again

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-macos

I had the same issue (I had v.1.17.0) and I could solve with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the option `-o` to specify the output format you need, an example of more info is `wide`, if you run  next command:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

The output will include the columns

```
NAME  READY  STATUS  RESTARTS  AGE  IP  NODE  NOMINATED NODE
```

But if you want a more custom output you can use `custom-columns` instead of `wide`, you can see the different options in the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns)

Comment: the -o wide flag does not help it does not add any column in my case, just NAME and AGE, no more information.